# Mac OSX Lion:making a wimax modem driver(device:greenpacket UH 235)

Tags: driver, osx-lion, wimax

I am using a wimax modem from **greenpacket,model is shuttle-UH235**. Since I bought it I searched a lot for a driver that will be compatible with **mac osx lion** as the driver they provided is built for **snow leopard**.I asked them several times but they did not pay any heed still now. I have decided to build one on my own using objective-c.Does anyone have any suggestions to get started?I mean how should I proceed,which things to consider as preliminary steps.Or is it wise to proceed to make something like this?A code snippet or explained example will do a great favor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **I checked the about menu of their windows version and I have found that they have used the following libs in developing it:openSSL,wpa_supplicant,BSD.Does it make any sense?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Apple I/O Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) to write device drivers for Mac OS X. I/O Kit drivers are written in a subset of C++ that is easier to work with in a kernel environment than either full C++ or Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you!There is an authentication part i.e. only a registered user can login using his login info. What sort of work do I need to do for it?I am quite a newbie in Mac.Could you please suggest some sort of examples or an explained hint? Thanks in advance. Here is the windows driver screenshots,I need to implement same one for Mac. [screeshot1](http://i39.tinypic.com/34orggy.png) [screeshot2](http://i43.tinypic.com/15p2upt.png) [screenshot3](http://i40.tinypic.com/jl32px.png)

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your question as a _winmodem_ question, not a _wimax_ question. I don't think `linmodems` source will be much help. All I've got left for advice is the I/O kit link.